# How to receive security update notification email?

Tags: admin, updates

I would like to know WordPress security and release update via email? Where can I subscribe email notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For release updates, you can sign up at https://wordpress.org/list/.

If you'd like more regular updates on the development process, visit https://make.wordpress.org/core/ and sign up there.